# Nested object members null after mapping with Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have an object

```
public class Tenant : EntityBase
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual string CreatorName { get; set; }
    public virtual TenantState State { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<TenantActivity> Activities { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<AppUser> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<TenantConfig> TenantConfigs { get; set; }

    ....
}
```

A DTO like so:

```
public class TenantDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CDate { get; set; }
    public string CUser { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string CreatorName { get; set; }
    public TenantState State { get; set; }
    public AddressDto Address { get; set; }
    public List<TenantActivityDto> Activities { get; set; }
    public List<AppUserDto> Users { get; set; }
    public List<TenantConfigDto> TenantConfigs { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

The class `Address` is a ValueObject which also has a DTO. I use the following mapping (standard, no special configs)

```
public class TenantMapperProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<Tenant, TenantDto>();
        CreateMap<TenantDto, Tenant>();
    }
}

public class AddressMapperProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<Address, AddressDto>();
        CreateMap<AddressDto, Address>();
    }
}
```

And in my App.xaml.cs I have:

```
        var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile<TenantMapperProfile>();
            cfg.AddProfile<TenantActivityMapperProfile>();
            cfg.AddProfile<AppUserMapperProfile>();
            cfg.AddProfile<AddressMapperProfile>();
            //cfg.ShouldMapProperty = p => p.SetMethod.IsPrivate || p.GetMethod.IsAssembly;
        });
        Mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();
```

Then I call it in a service like so:

```
    public TenantDto CreateTenant(TenantDto tenantDto)
    {
        tenantDto.CreatorName = creatingUserName;
        var tenant = _mapper.Map<Tenant>(tenantDto); 
        tenant = _tenantManagerService.CreateTenant(tenant);//<-- Screenshot made here
        return _mapper.Map<TenantDto>(tenant);
    }
```

After the first call to mapper I made a screenshot of my debugger window. As you can see the `tenantDto` instance contains data in the `Address` object but the `tenant`object contains its own data correctly mapped but the nested `Address` object has only null values! What am I doing wrong here??

**EDIT - additional information**

calling `mapperConfig.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` returns one error:

> The following property on Bedisoco.BedInventory.Sys.Models.Entities.Role cannot be mapped: 
>       Roles
>   Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the destination type Bedisoco.BedInventory.Sys.Models.Entities.Role.

The `Role` object is somewhere inside one of the Lists, I think the `User` object inside the `List<AppUser>` collection contains itself a list of `Role` objects. It is not even implemented completely.

*Am I wrong assuming that Automapper ignores such things silently*??

[image]

Comment: Try adding `mapperConfig.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` before calling `CreateMapper`. It should fail if you haven't given automapper enough info.

Comment: You also need to `CreateMap` for internal entities like `CreateMap<TenantActivity, TenantActivityDto>();` and so on.

Comment: I did so, I did not paste a dozen profile classes here. I have updated everything and `AssertConfigurationIsValid()` does NOT throw any exceptions anymore. But my `Address` object still contains only NULL values after the mapper call. This ends in an exception on the database for fields that do NOT allow NULL values.

Answer (score 3):

Ok solved it, was my own problem.

Most of my value objects contain a constructor with all fields and a private setter. Private setters are NO problem with Automapper if configured correctly (`cfg.ShouldMapProperty = p => p.SetMethod.IsPrivate || p.GetMethod.IsAssembly;`).

But VS or ReSharper suggested to make **auto properties 'get-only'**. This refactoring pleases VS but NOT Automapper!