# Automapper nested object null after mapping

Tags: null, nested, mapping, automapper

I have two entities :

```
public class TableA
  {

    public int id { get; set; }   
    public virtual TableB TableB { get; set; }
}



public class TableB
 {
   public TableB()
   {
     TableAList = new List<TableA>();
   }
   public int id { get; set; }
   public virtual List<TableA> TableAList { get; set; }
 }
```

And two classes

```
public class ClasseMetierA
  {
    private int id;
    public ClasseMetierB TableB;
}


public class ClasseMetierB
  {
                 public ClassMetierB()
        {
            TableAList = new List<ClasseMetierAList>();
        }
    private int id;   
    public List<ClasseMetierA> TableAList { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to convert TableB object into ClasseMetierB object.
I'm using automapper with this configuration :

```
mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {

                    cfg.CreateMap<TableA, ClasseMetierA>().MaxDepth(3);
                    cfg.CreateMap<TableB, ClasseMetierB>().MaxDepth(3);

        });
        mapperConfig.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

I'm calling this function to convert my object :

```
public B ConvertDTB(D obj)
    {
      var mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();
      return mapper.Map<B>(obj);
    }
```

The problem is the following :
When I convert an TableB object into a ClasseMetierB object, the properties of all the elements in TableAList are all null, even if the sources properties (TableB.TableAList) were not.

I found this post ([Nested object members null after mapping with Automapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296184/nested-object-members-null-after-mapping-with-automapper)) with a similar problem but the solution given just raise a null exception error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: I realized this was due to the fact my fields are private. I tried to handle that with cfg.ShouldMapProperty = pi =>
pi.GetMethod != null && (pi.GetMethod.IsPublic || pi.GetMethod.IsPrivate); but i'm getting a "Unmapped members were found" error

Comment: That error is telling you exactly what's unmapped. That means your config is broken and you have to fix it.